# Find the no. of requests made in last minute

Tags: algorithm

Given requests at random times, return the requests from the last 1 minute

This was a question asked in Microsoft technical interview. I could not find any more details about the problem. Can anyone suggest how to approach the problem

Answer (score 2):

This is really an interesting question which serves as a baseline for multiple cloud services which operate upon the idea of throttling. The ideology behind throttling is to limit the number of requests per second from a given client depending upon the throughput he's paying for. An example of such a service is DynamoDB from AWS.

Since cloud services usually have a high level of clients and traffic, one must design a solution-at-scale which works at high load. A queue would indeed be a data-structure of choice to handle such a scenario. However, would enqueuing and dequeuing millions of transaction per minute be efficient? A general way to avoid having a big queue tail is by introducing a precision trade-off through batching.

A blog which defines this concept in depth is this: https://medium.com/@saisandeepmopuri/system-design-rate-limiter-and-data-modelling-9304b0d18250

Let me know if you need any more explanation about the same. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Make a queue.

Add new requests to the queue tail.

After every adding and before checking remove too old ones from the queue head.

When checking needed -  return queue size

Comment: Or, after enqueue, dequeue all where their request time > 1 minute

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, I meant the same "after adding"